# "Show all except" in MySQL Boolean Full-Text Searches

Tags: sql, mysql

With MySQL Boolean Full-Text Searches...

> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-boolean.html
>
> A leading minus sign indicates that
>   this word must not be present in any
>   of the rows that are returned.
>
> Note: The - operator acts only to
>   exclude rows that are otherwise
>   matched by other search terms. Thus, a
>   boolean-mode search that contains only
>   terms preceded by - returns an empty
>   result. It does not return “all rows
>   except those containing any of the
>   excluded terms.”

Is there any way to do a search giving all rows except those that contain any of the excluded terms?

like (+* -blah -blah2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but it would be equivalent to simply `NOT` the condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM foo
WHERE NOT MATCH (bar) AGAINST ('blah blah2')
```

of course such a query can't possibly actually use the fulltext index for quick lookup.