# negation with match against

Tags: mysql, match, against

I want search those rows that do not contain "rajasthan" in the state field using match against in MySql.

My query is this:

```
SELECT * from member where MATCH(state) AGAINST('-rajasthan' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

However, it returns an empty set of result.

What is the problem with this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe this will do the trick:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  Member
WHERE 
  NOT MATCH (state) AGAINST ('+rajasthan' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Source: ["Show all except" in MySQL Boolean Full-Text Searches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3913777/show-all-except-in-mysql-boolean-full-text-searches)

**Beware** - I believe this will do a full table scan and this query will not benefit from the FullText index as you might hope.

**As to your empty result:**

> Note: The - operator acts only to exclude rows that are otherwise matched by other search terms. Thus, a boolean-mode search that contains only terms preceded by - returns an empty result. It does not return “all rows except those containing any of the excluded terms.”

[Source](http://www.globberstack.com/Questions/show-all-except-in-mysql-boolean-full-text-searches-1/)

Comment: can u suggest me alternate of query for being fast

Comment: You may consider this query: Select * FROM Member where State not like '%rajasthan%'                 However, my gut tells me this may be the same speed or slower. May be worth a try though

Answer (score -1):

The - operator acts only to exclude rows that are otherwise matched by other search terms. Thus, a boolean-mode search that contains only terms preceded by - returns an empty result. It does not return “all rows except those containing any of the excluded terms.”

So try appending to your query `OR 1 = 1` so that the query to return all your records without MATCH operator

Comment: OR 1 = 1 will also return records that you try to exclude by MATCH(state) AGAINST('-rajasthan' IN BOOLEAN MODE)