# MySQL multiple querys with most matching item on top

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL database containing items with a name.
I also have an array of keywords.
My plan is to send multiple queries to the database using something like

```
foreach($keywords as $keyword){
 $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM items WHERE name LIKE %$keyword%");   
}
```

After that I want to sort the results after the highest amout of matches, so that the item found using the most queries is on top while others are down below...

My questions:
Is this recommendable? Is this a performance killer?
If my idea is stupid, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @KoenHollander not sure, soundex against the list. Hmm

Comment: Using `name LIKE '%$keyword%' OR name LIKE '%$keyword2%'.......` would be better than multiple queries

Comment: How about this answer of mine [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30677347/1816093) ... last block, scroll over, column called `relevance` ?  `FULLTEXT` search btw

Comment: ^^^^^^ That looks better still

Comment: @Drew is there a way to exclude search results containing blacklisted words?

Comment: Yes, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37604988)

Comment: The above was for Stopwords. Probably not what you meant. Try thiis here http://stackoverflow.com/a/3914883